# find sum of infinite series.Why does it issue a zero amount?

Tags: c

[image]

You need to find the sums of an infinite series with a given accuracy.(the picture with the task is given as a link)
the program constantly counts the zero amount. I don't understand what my mistake is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
    int i;
    int n =1;
    double E,x,q;
    double sum = 0;

    scanf ("%f",&E) ;
    scanf ("%f",&x) ;

    q=pow(x,3)/6;

    while(fabs(q)>=E){

        if (n/2==0) {
            sum=sum+q;
        }
        else {
            sum=sum-q;
        }
        q=(q*pow(x,2))/(n+3);
        n=n+1;
    }
    printf("%f",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is your if statement right? Don't you mean n%2 == 0.

Comment: Maybe 
I need to check whether n is even or not.The program started producing at least some non-zero result after I changed f to lf.But I still don't know if I did this program correctly.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {
int i;
int n =1;
double E,x,q;
double sum = 0;
printf("enter E = ");
scanf ("%lf",&E) ;
printf("enter x = ");
scanf ("%lf",&x) ;
q=pow(x,3)/3;
while(fabs(q)>=E){

if (n%2==0) {sum=sum+q;}
else {
sum=sum-q;}
q=(q*pow(x,2)*(2*n+1))/(2*n+8);
n=n+1;
}
printf("%d %lf", n-1, sum);
return 0;
}

Comment: "Maybe I need to check whether n is even or not." n%2 == 0 does exactly this. Maybe you can update your question and leave a note about the improvements. Or if you have a new problem write a new one.

Answer (score 2):

It will never going to enter to that if statement. You are letting n=1 and it will be always 1, and u are doing n=n+1 in the else.

Comment: The code will enter the first if directly. By calculating with Integers 1/2 = 0. And he does increment the int after the else. After the first iteration the code will never enter the if.

Comment: He changed the code. Now the problem is other i see...

Comment: ah okay, sorry.